# How do I properly get formdata using Python's cgi module?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a date from my form data, but it keeps coming up as an error when running the module. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/weekday.py", line 19, in <module>
    weekday = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 113, in weekday
    return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is my code:

```
import cgi
import calendar

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>Weekday</title>
</head><body>
"""

year= form.getvalue("year")
month= form.getvalue("month")
day= form.getvalue("day")

weekday = calendar.weekday(year, month, day) 

if weekday == 0: 
   print "<p> That's a Monday </p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `int()` on the form value like so:

```
year= int(form.getvalue("year"))
month= int(form.getvalue("month"))
day= int(form.getvalue("day"))
```

Comment: I tried this and get: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/weekday.py", line 15, in <module>
    year= int(form.getvalue("year"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Comment: @aaandrewp that would be because you don't have a "year" value posted in your form, then.

Comment: If it's None then you didn't get any value from the form.

Comment: @WayneWerner the form is given as follows: "Enter the date (yyyy, mm, dd): 
<input type="text" name="year" size="4" maxlength="4" />
<input type="text" name="month" size="2" maxlength="2" />
<input type="text" name="day" size="2" maxlength="2" />
</p>

Comment: What you've defined in the html is irrelevant. What matters is [how http request/responses work](http://www.silicon-press.com/briefs/brief.http/brief.pdf), and that your script isn't getting any form data POSTed to it.